# Generating XPATH Query issue

Tags: java, xpath

I have a SOAP Response as below

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Body>
<NTService.DisconnectResourceResult     xmlns="http://www.evolving.com/NumeriTrack/xsd">
<retData xmlns="">
<retCode>rcSuccess</retCode>
<retMsg/>
<resErrList/>
</retData>
</NTService.DisconnectResourceResult>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Am not good in generating XPATH query, but using SOAPUI I was able to fetch the XPATH query to fetch `retCode` as below :

```
//ns1:NTService.DisconnectResourceResult[1]/retData[1]/retCode[1]/text()
```

In Java, am trying to fetch `retCode` but am unable to fetch the output.

```
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
xpath.setNamespaceContext(new SoapNamespaceContext());

String     sxpath="//ns1:NTService.DisconnectResourceResult[1]/retData[1]/retCode[1]/text()";
System.out.println("sxpath is " + sxpath);
XPathExpression expr;
expr = xpath.compile(sxpath);
System.out.println("expr is " + expr);
Object result;
result = expr.evaluate(sb, XPathConstants.NODESET);
System.out.println("result is " + result);
NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;
System.out.println("Length of result is " + nodes.getLength());
 for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
     System.out.println(nodes.item(i).getNodeValue()); 
 }
```

I have set the namespace as well.

```
public String getNamespaceURI(String prefix) {
        System.out.println("Prefix is " +prefix);
      if (prefix == null) throw new NullPointerException("Null prefix");
        else if ("ns1".equals(prefix)) {
            System.out.println("Returning http://www.evolving.com/NumeriTrack/xsd");
            return "http://www.evolving.com/NumeriTrack/xsd";
                    }
        else if ("n".equals(prefix)) {
            System.out.println("Returning http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
            return "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
                    }
        else if ("xml".equals(prefix)) return XMLConstants.XML_NS_URI;
        return XMLConstants.NULL_NS_URI;
}
```

`

Can anyone please suggest me to get retCode from the SOAP Message response.

Thanks

Comment: namespace prefixes are only aliases for namespace uris and can change therefore it's not a good idea to discover namespace uris by prefixes since the same prefix may alias different namespace uris (even in the same document).

Comment: But, in my current scenario, I think the namespace uris is same in the  whole envelop. Can you please suggest what I may need to change in code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the anserw :

```
            Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(new File("D:\\Loic_Workspace\\Test2\\res\\test.xml"));


        System.out.println(doc.getElementsByTagName("retCode").item(0).getTextContent());
```

**You should use .getTextContent() method.**

Will output **rcSuccess** as you want :)

Hope it's helps,